# Selenium Unable to Locate HTML elements Except with ID

Tags: python, jsp, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to write a python program using selenium and unfortunately I faced a strange problem. I have web-page written in JSP, where I can't access elements with `.find_element_by_*` commands, except with `.find_elements_by_id`. None of tags can be located.

If I access some elements with its ID, then I can access to its children by other find commands (e.g. `tag_name`, `name`, etc). For example, if I have this HTML:

```
<div id="myId">
    <div name="myName">Test Div</div>
</div>
```

I can access inner `div` with `.find_element_by_id("myId").find_element_by_name("myName")` but I can't access it using `.find_element_by_name("myName")` and if I use `.find_elements_by_tag_name("div")` for the whole HTML, I got an empty list.

Actually my web-page is compatible with IE 7, I tried to set parameter version in `desired_capabilities`, but it didn't help and the web-driver loads with IE 10 as default.

**EDIT 1:**

Here is the python script that I used:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def my_method(web_driver = "Firefox"):
    # launch web-driver
    if web_driver.upper() == "IE":
        driver = webdriver.Ie()
        print "IE"

    else:
        driver = webdriver.Firefox()
        print "FireFox"

    # navigating
    driver.get("http://python.org")

    # accessing elements
    ## .find_by_tag_name
    e = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("html")
    print "number of html tags: " + str(len(e))

    e = e[0].find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    print "number of A tags using html tag: " + str(len(e))

    e = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")
    print "number of A tags: " + str(len(e))

    e = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("body")
    print "number of body tags: " + str(len(e))

    e = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("html")
    e = e[0].find_elements_by_tag_name("body")
    print "number of body tags using html tag: " + str(len(e))

    ## .find_by_xpath
    e = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a")
    print "number of A xpath: " + str(len(e))

    e = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body")
    print "number of body xpath: " + str(len(e))

    ## .find_by_class_name
    e = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("reference")
    print "number of A using class name: " + str(len(e))

    ## .find_by_css_selector
    e = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("a[class='reference']")
    print "number of A using css selector: " + str(len(e))

    driver.close()

# execute
my_method(web_driver = "Firefox")
my_method(web_driver = "Ie")
```

**EDIT 2:**

In the HTML we have to separate parts: a menu and a main page. Each one has an HTML tag and is rendered separately. The result HTML code in both parts is simple and is similar to this:

```
<html lang="en_us">
    <body>
        <div id="testdiv">
        <table align="center" border="0">
            <tr bgcolor="#666666">
                <td><img src="img.jpg"/></td>
                <td><div id="message" style="color:white;font-size:12px;font-    weight:bold;">message</div></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT 3:**

If anyone is familiar with JSP, I want to know how JSP tags would be converted to HTML tags, since it can help me to detect the problem about accessing tags.

Comment: that is _very_ strange.. i've never seen that type of behavior.

Comment: @user1177636 I tried [this code](http://snk.to/f-c7xigls9) for [Python Site](http://python.org) and it works completely fine; but when I'm using it for my own web-page with respective information, it returns 0 for every find command and just detects HTML tag.

Comment: BTW, don't you have any idea about IE version compatibility?

Comment: @ZeinabAbbasi: It can be one of many reasons, so your need provide more info to rule out other possible reasons. At this stage, it's unlikely.

Comment: @user1177636 what do you mean by more info?

Comment: @user1177636 I've put the code in the question, but unfortunately I don't have the JSP code and I posted the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for trying to help me out in this issue. I solved the problem and I thought it would be great to share the solution.

Actually there was something that I didn't pay attention to; there were multiple frames in the page and I had to switch between frames to get access to elements. So for switching to each frame first I used `.switch_to_default_content()` to switch to the main content and then `.switch_to_frame(frame_object)` to switch to the desired frame.

Answer (score 0):

This happens. I also faced same issue once.

I solved it using XPath. For your problem, the XPath expression would be:

```
//div/div[contains(@name,"myName")]
```

OR

```
//div[contains(@name,"myName")]
```

OR

```
//div[text()="Test Div"]
```

OR

```
//div[@id="myId"]/div
```

Comment: I tried the X-Path; it didn't work. I've posted the code in the above comments.

Comment: Did you try on Firefox ?

Comment: Yes, I tried it on firefox and IE; but keep in mind that my web-page is compatible with IE 7.

Comment: @Michael Petrotta I'm familiar with a lot of ways to access elements using selenium, but there is something else that causes this problem. I think it's about JSP codes, because my codes works in another sites and this is the reason that I've added JSP tag to my question.